# javascript full text Date() format with PHP carbon

Tags: javascript, php, date, php-carbon

I am generating and sending full date string from javascript Date() function which returns full string date format like this:

```
Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

Carbon parser wont accept this format for creating the same date on server side. This does not work:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)');
```

**Error** *Failed to parse time string (Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)) at position 41 (l): Double timezone specification*

If I remove `(Central European Standard Time)` works:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100');
```

Then it correctly creates date.

Can JS default Date() be used in Carbon somehow or will I have to format date before sending it to Carbon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Carbon extends PHP's native [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class, so you can use `createFromFormat` instead:

```
$date = 'Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)';
$carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s e+', $date);
```

The important part of the format specification is the `+` at the end, which tells it to ignore any trailing data.

See https://3v4l.org/Rnen7 for a demo (using `DateTime` rather than `Carbon`)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the date in ISO format, Carbon understands ISO format. You can get the date in ISO format using `new Date().toISOString()`

Comment: Can you please explain with an example.